# Difference between module es2015 vs es2020

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

What is the difference between `module` **es2015** and **es2020** option in ts.config?

In other words, is there any difference if I use [es2015 modules](http://es6-features.org/#ValueExportImport) and configure the `module` option to `es2015` or `es2020`?

ts-config:

```
{
/* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
  module: 'es2015'
}
```

vs

```
{
  ...
  "module": "es2020"
  ...
}
```

I do not want the `target` or `lib` difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the documentation for that option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module):

> If you are wondering about the difference between ES2015 (aka ES6) and ES2020, ES2020 adds support for dynamic imports, and import.meta.